# ThreadPool - loop until all threads completed in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm trying to speed up a code with threads and ThreadPool but I'm not able to wait until all threads are executed before exiting sub.

I've tryed many ways, the code below is my last attempt.
It waits but not until all threads are ended.

Where I'm wrong?

```
Public ThrStarted As Integer

Sub Main

        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10)

        Dim ArrVal() As Object
        For LitiThr% = 0 To Liti.getUpperbound(1)
            Erase ArrVal
            ArrVal = {Liti(3, LitiThr), Liti(0, LitiThr), CInt(Liti(4, LitiThr)), CInt(Liti(1, CicloLitiThr)), CInt(Liti(2, LitiThr))}

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf mThread), ArrVal)
        Next CicloLitiThr
        Dim workerThreads%
        Dim completionPortThreads%
        Do
            ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(workerThreads, completionPortThreads)

            Me.lblTotal.Text = workerThreads & " / " & completionPortThreads
            Me.TBox_LitiUpd.Text = LitiUpd.ToString
            Application.DoEvents()

        'With This I want to wait until all threads executed but it doesn't seems to work
        Loop Until (ThrStarted - 1) = Liti.getUpperbound(1) And workerThreads = 0

End Sub



Sub mThread(ByVal ArrVal() As Object) 


    ThrStarted += 1

    'Some code

End Sub
```

I've read many questions/Answers and I found that many tips were for switching to "Parallel.ForEach" but I wasn't able to change my code (It's my first try with threads).

UPDATE:

Following your advice (+1 for the incentive) I changed my code as below but now I'm not able to show status of threads on UI.

I'm afraid that I can't use "await" because I'm using VS2010 express and (on MSDN) I've read:
"The Async and Await keywords were introduced in Visual Studio 2012."

So, what can I do?

```
        Dim mDaPass(Liti.getUpperbound(1)) As Object
        Dim mDaIns() As Object
        For LitiThr% = 0 To Liti.getUpperbound(1)
            Erase mDaIns
            mDaIns = {Liti(3, LitiThr), Liti(0, LitiThr), CInt(Liti(4, LitiThr)), CInt(Liti(1, LitiThr)), CInt(Liti(2, LitiThr))}
            mDaPass(LitiThr%) = mDaIns
        Next LitiThr
        Parallel.ForEach(mDaPass, AddressOf mThread)

        Task.WaitAll()
```

Comment: 99 times out of 100 when someone says "I'm trying to speed up a code with threads" the code will be slower, buggier, and/or much harder to maintain. Make sure that you are certain that you get an actual performance increase that is worth the maintenance cost.

Comment: Also, 9,999 times out of 10,000 if you are using `Application.DoEvents()` in your code then you are doing something wrong!

Comment: Also, 999,999 times out of 1,000,000 if you are accessing the same variables in different threads without any form of locking then you are doing something wrong! (i.e. `ThrStarted`)

Comment: @Enigmativity I've tested with and without and using threads is faster. I use DoEvents because without it labels and textbox don't show the new value

Comment: @Enigmativity ThrStarted is only a counter I used (no different ideas)

Comment: You are clearly using `ThrStarted` from multiple threads - that can lead to unexpected values when reading and writing values at the same time. You shouldn't no it.

Comment: `DoEvents` forces the UI-thread's message pump to process events which can lead to recurrency and/or stack overflow issues. It's better to find another way of updating your controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread pool is a global resource. Don't mess with it's configuration. You can't reliably query the number of available threads etc. because the pool is shared for the entire process. You need to throw this away.

Make yourself familiar with modern .NET threading APIs. All of this is obsolete.

I can't read that VB code well. Probably you want to start some tasks (e.g. a `List<Task>`) and then use `Task.WaitAll` to wait until they are all done.

Don't use `DoEvents`. Use one of the standard techniques to keep the UI thread unblocked. For example `await`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already write that I've read about using "Parallel.ForEach" but I'm a self-taught and I'm very new to vb.net (I've learned a bit of VBA and now I'm trying to switch). There is nothing to do in the code after execution of TreadPool. I only want to display on the form: "end of execution" . I use "DoEvents"  to update the labels and TextBox on the form. I don't understand why loop stops when about 3-4 threads still running.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. Throw that code away and do it right which is actually much easier than what you are attempting to do right now. You are setting yourself up for failure. If you insist on a DoEvents loop: `while (true) { DoEvents(); Sleep(10); if(Task.WhenAll(myTasks).Completed) break; }`.

Comment: @genespos the new code is much better now. `Parallel.ForEach` is blocking the UI thread. As a simple fix you could try `await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(...));` translated to VB. The call to `Task.WaitAll` with empty arguments does nothing.

Comment: I'm using VS2010 express and it seems not to accept `await`. `Task.WaitAll()` works! The code waits until all threads are completed. Please, if possible, write vb.net code: I find it hard to translate from C to vb.net. Thanks